# I'm trying to learn how to create a virtual assistant, and I encountered this error

Tags: python

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyttsx3
import pywhatkit

listener = sr.Recognizer()
engine = pyttsx3.init()
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
engine.setProperty('voice', voices[1].id)


def talk(text):
    engine.say(text)
    engine.runAndWait()


def take_command():
    try:
        with sr.Microphone() as source:
            print('listening...')
            voice = listener.listen(source)
            command = listener.recognize_google(voice)
            command = command.lower()
            if 'robot' in command:
                command = command.replace('robot', '')
                print(command)
    except:
        pass
    return command


def run_robot():
    command = take_command()
    print(command)
    if 'play' in command:
        song = command.replace('play', '')
        talk('playing' + song)
        pywhatkit.playonyt(song)


run_robot()
```

Error:

```
listening...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/CyberDash-/PycharmProjects/AIProject/main.py", line 40, in <module>
    run_robot()
  File "C:/Users/CyberDash-/PycharmProjects/AIProject/main.py", line 32, in run_robot
    command = take_command()
  File "C:/Users/CyberDash-/PycharmProjects/AIProject/main.py", line 28, in take_command
    return command
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'command' referenced before assignment

Process finished with exit code 1
```

What's the problem here? While I'm using my headset everything is going fine, but after I remove my headset, the program works but without interaction with the robot. I can see the word "listening...." but nothing happens after, until I stop the program and see this message.

Comment: In except block, replace `pass` with `command = None`

Comment: If the try block encounters an error in the first few lines, `command` is never defined.

Comment: `except: pass` is very unhelpful in code that you are trying to debug.

Comment: `except: pass` is very dangerous.  You're deliberately ignoring the error, and so you have no idea what went wrong.

Comment: Yes, but they didn't ask for a code review, only for help with the error they got.

Comment: @rv.kvetch. The real problem is hidden because the OP catch all exceptions otherwise the exception would be raised sooner. See my answer.

Comment: I disagree, there is no error hidden due to the use of `except: pass`, at least not in this case. Even if it had been a more specific error that was handled, like `except TypeError: pass`, we would still eventually run into the same error as in the question (UnboundLocalError). In this case, it's actually *lucky* that the OP declared it as `except: pass`, otherwise he never would have realized there was a scenario where `command` could be undefined.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Catch and pass all exception is a very bad idea.

```
def take_command():
    try:  # <- GOOD
        with sr.Microphone() as source:  # <- (1) The problem may be HERE
            print('listening...')
            voice = listener.listen(source)  # <- (2) or HERE
            command = listener.recognize_google(voice)
            command = command.lower()
            if 'robot' in command:
                command = command.replace('robot', '')
                print(command)
    except:  # <- BAD, you catch all exception
        pass  # <- BAD++, an exception is raised and you do... nothing 
    return command  # <- (3) because the command variable is undefined so the problem occurs before command was defined
```

Comment: I've tried to add "-1 because reason" before and it's always refused me adding a comment (linked to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment)). I'd assume SO directly doesn't want us commenting on the reason for a downvote, at least based on the article.

Comment: again removed DV